# What does web worker do when owner not in focus?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-worker

[edit: this question MAY need narrower scope, so I will state that I am currently using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m (64-bit) with default settings when I notice this. I am currently using HTTPS, but I observed it before the switch.]

I have an application that hands AJAX polling off to web workers. It's not an incredible savings in terms of performance, but it makes the application more easily reasoned and has potential for future performance benefits.

I add a console logging line to the worker so that it just tells me every time the XHR request is made. As you may know, when duplicates of logging lines come into Chrome, the Inspector just records the number of duplicates.

As I view the page, I can see in the console: `(52) XHR invoked`

If I have the page in focus, I see that integer increase every 2 seconds, per my polling interval.

HOWEVER,

When I switch to another tab for a while, and then return, it takes several seconds for that number to update, at which time it only updates by one. That might be because the worker is actually pausing, which is fine in this particular application, or it might be that the worker is still running but the console API just can't receive the logging line from the worker if the parent isn't visible. Not sure.

But the important thing I'm trying to solve is the delay when I return to the tab. If it's a responsively updating dashboard, a delay of 10-60 seconds before updates continue is noticeable and is a UI performance bug.

Can anybody shed some insight into what happens with the web worker when the owner tab loses focus? Is it actually queueing up each instance of the work that needs to be done (on XHR message) and then doing it when the owner comes back?

Would manually pausing the polling mechanism on lost focus help anything?

Comment: Have you considered adding a timestamp to the log output? Doesn't sound like a hard thing to do...

Comment: It would, for example, verify whether it's the worker that goes idle, or the message channel or the console. I had used workers for some while for different stuff and they didn't pause when I left the tab, so I have reasons to think the problem is located elsewhere.

Comment: If the worker was still running, as I suspect, the timestamps on the output would be coherent (eg. one every 30 seconds). Frankly first thing you should've done is make a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem. Now I'm only guessing what could cause this. Does it even happen when you simplify the code?

Comment: [removed comments owing to 'this seems like chat' warning-- will delete this one eventually, too!] Tomas, I will see what happens when there's no Ajax polling; however, I feel that it's the very doing of network-involved tasks that might be triggering the issue. Removing the complexity is not reproducing the scenario.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour will vary between browsers. Most of them will reduce JavaScript priority to preserve CPU cycles and performance overhead if the tab is not used. I believe some browsers suspend the tab execution entirely so yes it will be a pause until back in focus. I think Firefox has an option to control this.

Comment: By default, main thread execution in any browser that I use will continue fairly unobstructed. Now, historically I have implemented explicit methods to pause polling (don't need the data, why ask for it?) but this unexpected behaviour has me curious. Any idea what Chrome's strategy is by default, with regards to Web Workers?

Answer (score 2):

WebWorkers are tightly bound to the page that created them. The default behavior is to suspend a WebWorker when it's page is not active.

A typical problem scenario is a WebWorker managing a WebSocket. That network connection is still active when execution is suspended, receiving messages but not processing them. This will cause the WebSocket's internal network buffers to overflow - essentially a memory leak, which can crash the entire system.

The solution is to use SharedWorkers which are not tightly bound to the page that created them and are designed to operate between pages, ignoring focus loss. The WebSocket scenario is a perfect use for a SharedWorker.

The use cases for any SharedWorker should be well understood, since they are always running and can affect the performance of other pages and apps.

Note that some browsers do not support SharedWorkers.